# How Can You Use Djipi's Cel-Shading N64 Zelda Textures on OS X?

Tags: macos, emulation, nintendo-64

Someone named [Djipi](http://www.emutalk.net/members/13070-Djipi) made a collection of hi-res textures that made [Ocarina of Time](http://www.emulation64.com/files/info/961/) and [Majora's Mask](http://www.emulation64.com/files/info/958/) look like Wind Waker. They look pretty incredible, as seen here: [The Legend of Zelda ocarina of time HD texture/cell Shade Djipi Update: Bosses Part 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YVbtb9f-LQU) .

I use the console ui of [mupen64plus 2.0.0](http://code.google.com/p/mupen64plus/) installed via [homebrew](http://brew.sh/) with the [glide64mk2](https://github.com/mupen64plus/mupen64plus-video-glide64mk2) video plugin (because I can't get [rice](https://github.com/mupen64plus/mupen64plus-video-rice) to work very well without glitches) on an 11" Macbook Air running Mavericks.

I've tried to follow various tutorials on how to get this to work([HiRes Textures on Mupen64Plus AE v1.9.2](http://www.paulscode.com/forum/index.php?topic=511.0), [HiRes textures Glide64mk2](http://www.emutalk.net/threads/54776-HiRes-textures-Glide64mk2)) but to no avail.

So, my question is, what are the step by step instructions for getting up and running with Djipi's cel-shading textures for OoT and MM on a Mac?

Comment: Nice revision! Your question might be a bit more appealing if you add a specific picture too, instead of just linking to a google image search.